# Impl Into<B> trait for all types which impl Into<A>

Tags: rust

I wanted to implement a conversion trait that would cover all types supporting already existing conversion. I thought that this could be done in following way:

```rust
impl<T> Into<B> for T
where
    T: Into<A>,
{
  fn into(self) -> B {
    let a: A = self.into();
    B::CaseA(a)
  }
}
```

However compiler throws a following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::Into<block::ItemContent>`
   --> yrs\src\block.rs:945:1
    |
945 | / impl<T> Into<B> for T
946 | | where
947 | |     T: Into<A>,
948 | | {
...   |
952 | |     }
953 | | }
    | |_^
    |
    = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
            - impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
              where U: From<T>;

error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`B`)
   --> yrs\src\block.rs:945:6
    |
945 | impl<T> Into<B> for T
    |      ^ type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`B`)
    |
    = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
    = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I'm looking for a way to automatically extend conversion for a new type for all instances, that support conversion to another existing type.

Comment: Is `B` defined in your crate? If so, you could implement `From<T> for B` instead of `Into<B> for T`: `impl<T> From<T> for B where T: Into<A> { fn from(t: T) -> Self { let a: A = t.into(); B::CaseA(a) } }`. That way you automatically get both `From` and `Into` - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15772767b7de0fa2ccb1cb5166ab4aeb

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do can be achieved (as the error says) by covering `T` with a local type. The reason you cannot do it without that is because otherwise someone else could also do the same and the Rust won't be able to tell which `impl` to use.   So you need a local *wrapper* type to keep the separation.

The complete reasoning behind this is referenced in the error explanation:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md

And https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.html

hope this helps ;)

A